# Binding to view in angular 2 from multilayer object that implements a custom interface

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I am trying to bind the variables within an object into my view.

I have imported all what needs to be imported - I implemented a resolver for the routes so that data is fetched before view loading.

If I bind `{{ test | json }}` inside my HTML, I get the full object and sub objects (all 3 layers).

If I bind `{{ test.abc.def }}` I get an error. Cannot read property 'def' of undefined.

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    public test: ABCTest = this.route.snapshot.data as ABCTest;
}
```

I f I try to reach it from my component code (inside the ngOnInit function), I get that abc is undefined aswell. Though if I log this.route.snapshot.data I get the full object in the console and I can open the sub-objects and view them.

My interface looks something like this:

```
export interface ABCTest {
    abc?: {
        def?: string;
    }
    ....
}
```

Any help on how I can access the subobjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access the data after accing the snapshot data correctly via the variable I identified in my resolver.

Lets say the resolve object is the following:

```
    {
        test: testResolver
}
```

To access the data i used: test = this.route.snapshot.data["test"] as TestInterface

Then i used test.abc.def within my html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Just did a quick test and It worked fine for me.

```
export interface ABCTest {
    abc?: {
        def?: string;
    }
    ....
}
```

Class declaration:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  public test: ABCTest;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.test = this.route.snapshot.data as ABCTest;
  }
}
```

Comment: I still cannot access def. It tells me that abc is undefined.